# Capture console.log to a file?

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

I'm running a Chrome kiosk and want to retain and aggregate logs. The Chrome docs say that you can use `--enable-logging --v=1` and it will log the to the chrome_debug.log file. Doing this creates a log, but it's all system-level stuff within Chrome and not the site-specific logs. Is there a way to capture all my console.log/info/warn statements straight to a file? Or do I need to engineer something?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are in control of the code, or you can inject code, you can override console.log to collect the messages.

```
var aggrLog = '';
(function(){
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function (message) {
        aggrLog += Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' ') + '\n';
        oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    };
})();
```

This will aggregate all the console.log in variable aggrLog.

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log

Modern browsers allows to save local data to file, you'll need a trigger to decide when to save. see more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript